# How to Perform a TFS get to a supplied or current directory path, ignoring workspace settings

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2010 and writing a script to enable a simple get of specific version label of our software.  Since this is only a simple get, is there anyway to just perform a get without having to use the current workspace settings or change the workspace settings to the desired path? There is no reason to link the files to CM after the get, so I have no reason to preserve this 'workspace'. I just want to be able to create a directory anywhere I want and get TFS to give me a copy of the current version labeled files at the current directory, or to a directory I supply 'on the fly'.  There seems to be no way to seperate a simple get from the project workspace settings.  Am I missing something or am I forced to cloak or change workspace settings before the get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you do a TFS get without needing a workspace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712655/can-you-do-a-tfs-get-without-needing-a-workspace)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need a workspace to do a `get`, but it need not be the same workspace that you're using for Visual Studio.  In fact, you can just create a simple throwaway workspace, for example:

```
# {{Server}} is http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection; for readability.

tf workspace /new temp_workspace /collection:{{server}} /noprompt
tf workfold /map $/Project/Project C:\Build\Project
tf get C:\Build\Project /recursive /noprompt
tf workspace /delete temp_workspace /collection:http{{server}} /noprompt
```

---

Note that the TFS SDK does provide mechanisms to do a download of an `Item` without needing to create a workspace, so you could write a program to do this, but it would be a fair amount of code to avoid creating a workspace which is, ultimately, a fairly inexpensive operation.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  I'll go with creating a temp workspace, get the files, and immediately delete the temp workspace after a successful file retrieval.  I still think that there should be a command line switch for tf get that simply sets this temporary folder location for you.  The whole purpose is to not attach any of the files with a workspace in the first place since no edits are ever going to be made from this location!

Comment: @DeanRoberson: fair point, I'll make sure that gets noted.  Thanks!

Comment: Anyway to make this fully unattended via a script?  Everytime I create a workspace (tf workspace /new) I get a GUI window to verify the workspace creation.  Everytime I delete the temporary workspace(tf workspace /delete) it prompts for a y/n response.  Don't see a switch for this in the tf command line utility documentation.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry.  `/noprompt` is the flag you're looking for there.  (This is the implicit default in the cross-platform client, but it must be explicitly specified in the Windows command-line client.)

Comment: I added flags needed to actually retrieve all the files rooted at the given directory. Also the /noprompt flags mentioned above.

Comment: Whoa, @WillBickford I agree with the `/recursive`, what's with the `/force /overwrite`?!

Comment: In my case I'm updating a local directory for a build server. Probably overkill for normal use. The directory also starts out empty in my case.

Answer (score 1):

[Neno Loje created a small utility that offers this functionality in one command from the commandline](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/03/14/download-files-from-tfs-version-control-and-set-the-file-last-access-timestamp-to-the-file-s-last-check-in-time.aspx).

Comment: This looks like a great little tool!