# Download Project Visual Studio Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I wanted to download a project from TFS (Without mapping to a folder). Is there any way for me to download the entire project without actually mapping it? If yes, what are the steps I need to take in order to download the files?

Comment: You can use a temp workspace - described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10624570/600559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by the product out-of-the-box. You need to always [map a folder first, then you can download the files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10624570/736079). However [Neno Loje created a small utility that does this in one go](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/03/14/download-files-from-tfs-version-control-and-set-the-file-last-access-timestamp-to-the-file-s-last-check-in-time.aspx).