# Ant Build.xml to get latest from TFS server and create war file in local

Tags: ant, tfs, build, automation

I want to create a ant build file, which connects to TFS and get all the latest code for any particular and create a war file in my local out of it.

Is it possible? If yes, please guide me how can do it? I couldn't find much in google about this implementation.

I found this [Command line "get latest" from TFS without mapping workspaces and such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760851/command-line-get-latest-from-tfs-without-mapping-workspaces-and-such) , but here they are doing the same thing using command prompt.

Comment: There seems to be a chicken/egg problem here... Why would you want the build script to get the source? The build script is source.

Comment: I want an independent script which will always take latest from the repository and build my projects and start my local server. It is a kind of automation , we are doing.